# Why am I seeing the model objects on the bottom of view (Rails 5.1+)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just started a new rails application and saw something unusual (I just upgraded my Rails to 5.1 today so maybe it is a new feature? I could not get a good google result somehow).

Here is what I am talking about. Note on the last paragraph, it says `[#<Event id:1, title: "My...]`. I did not explicitly write any code to show that.

[image: page with weird objects]

This is what my `events/index.html.erb`  looks like

```
<h1>Events#index</h1>
<div>
  <%= @events.each do |event| %>
    <ul>
      <li><%= event.title %></li>
      <li><%= event.description %></li>
      <li><%= event.happening_at %></li>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

My controller also is very basic:

```
def index
  @events = Event.all
end
```

I did not install any new gems (yet). I just `rails new myApp` and installed RSpec and Devise, that's it.

What is causing my view to display what looks like `Event.all`?

*I am using `Rails 5.1.4` and `Ruby 2.2.5`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `=` in `<%=` in loop and that should do. The `=` causes the records to be displayed.

Use `<% @events.each do |event| %>` instead

Answer (score 1):

Replace `<%= @events.each do |event| %>` with `<% @events.each do |event| %>`. This displays all the record in object.